# Pygame on python 3.8, OSX will not display window... or is something wrong?

Tags: python, macos, pygame, python-3.8

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
GAME_WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

run = True

while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

pygame.quit()
```

im sure this is set up correctly to open a basic window, theres no errors, just gets stuck at a bouncing python 3 luncher

any suggestions?

Comment: pygame is not supported on Python 3.8 yet.

Comment: Tested. Works fine in Python 3.6.

Comment: thanks for feedback, switching to 3.6 now

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pygame is not yet supported with 3.8 so you should downgrade to Python 3.7 and everything should work there.

(Install pygame with: `pip install pygame`)

Sorry for the inconvenience, hope you get it working. Good luck!